# Reformat ip from ansible_facts without filter

Tags: syntax, ansible

I'm trying to dynamically update and reformat a host IP address for a template to use. I need to get the host IP, and reformat it from typical format into a format without a supporting filter.

I'm very new to ansible. *Very* new.

However, from what I've gathered...

1. I should be able to get the host ip "fact" from my playbook. I'm struggling with the syntax to get it to run,  but I'm pretty confident that's something I will be able to do.
2. Once I have the ip, I need to reformat it from 11.22.33.44 into 11\\.22\\.33\\.44 .

So far, I can't even get the syntax right for grabbing the ip fact, let alone reformat it. With regard to the formatting, I've scoured the filters, but didn't find any (explicit) descriptions that would indicate a filter method that would format in the manner I need (though... I'd suspect it exists).

```
name: "test gathering a fact"
   debug: var= "{{ hostvars[groups['webservers'][0]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

I expected something along the lines of...

11.22.33.44

But I'm getting:

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to have been in '/home/my_playbook.yml': line 14, column 13, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
  -  name: "test gathering a fact"
        debug: var= "{{ hostvars[groups['webservers'][0]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
        ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once I have the ip, I need to reformat it from 11.22.33.44 into 11\\.22\\.33\\.44 .

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ the_host.ansible_default_ipv4.address | regex_replace('\.', '\\\\.') }}
    # watch out if you choose not to use the `>-` syntax
    # as then yaml quoting will become a real PITA
    vars:
      the_host: '{{ hostvars[groups.webservers[0]] }}'
```

You also might be happier using `ansible_default_ipv4.address` instead of `ansible_eth0.ipv4.address` for machines that don't always use `eth0` (which is some modern ubuntu flavors, freebsd, etc). That is to say, you likely care about the machine's network identity, and not -- specifically -- what address is bound to a NIC named `eth0`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get over the hurdle, but oddly enough I'm not getting an error about set_fact not being applicable to Playbooks. "ERROR! 'set_fact' is not a valid attribute for a Play". I'm editing my post with updates...

Comment: well, if you actually are indenting your files the way you are indenting your question, that's a damn fine reason it wouldn't work; yaml is **extraordinarily** whitespace sensitive

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the white space more in mind. The indentation of the question is just a result of my not being 100% familiar with formatting stuff on stackoverflow yet. It didn't come out the way it was as a preview, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

indentation is wrong. Instead of

```
- name: "test gathering a fact"
     debug: var= ...
```

The correct syntax is

```
- name: "test gathering a fact"
  debug: var= ...
```

Comment: And also `var="{{` is almost always bad news; likely OP wanted `msg="{{`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the dot notation:

```
  - name: first debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[groups['webservers'][0]].ansible_enp0s25.ipv4.address }}"
```

And that code returns this in the output:

```
TASK [first debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "192.168.65.105"
}
```

So combining these together into this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: first debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[groups['webservers'][0]].ansible_enp0s25.ipv4.address }}"

  - name: second debug
    debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ hostvars[groups['webservers'][0]].ansible_enp0s25.ipv4.address | regex_replace('\.', '\\\\.') }}
```

Gives this output:

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [first debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "192.168.65.105"
}

TASK [second debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "192\\\\.168\\\\.65\\\\.105"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```